# Parametrization of classical moduli space for SUSY QED

Tags: gauge-theory, supersymmetry, moduli

#### A bit of context

I'm following [Bertolini's notes](https://people.sissa.it/%7Ebertmat/susycourse.pdf) on SUSY and in section 5.3.1 he claims that, for a SUSY theory without superpotential, i.e. in which the $D$-flat directions coincides with the moduli space, there are two equivalent definitions of the moduli space. The first one is already known and says that the space of $D$-flat directions is defined as the set of scalar field VEVs satysfing the $D$-flat conditions modulo gauge transformations; so the moduli space is
$$
\mathcal{M}_{cl}=\Big\{ \langle\phi\rangle \;|\;D^a=0\;\forall a \Big\}/\text{gauge transformations} \ , \tag{1}
$$
where $a$ is the gauge index and $D^a$ is the $D$-term of the vector superfield. The second definition is that the moduli space is parametrized by all single-trace, gauge-invariant operator VEVs made out of scalar fields, modulo *classical relations* between them, i.e.
$$
\mathcal{M}_{cl}=\Big\{ \langle\text{Gauge invariant operators}\equiv X_r(\phi)\rangle \Big\}/\text{classical relations} \ . \tag{2}
$$
He doesn't specify what these classical relations are, but he provides two example to clarify the meaning of it. Moreover, he doesn't prove the equivalence between the two definition, which I believe is found in [[1](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9506098)], but he does show that the dimension of the space obtained in the two ways is the same.

My problem is that I can't reach the same result he find in one of the example. I will now expose the problem.

#### The SUSY QED case

(The following,until the next header, is essentially copy-pasted from the notes.)

We consider massless SUSY QED, i.e. a Super Yang-Mills theory with gauge group $U(1)$, a flavour global symmetry $SU(F)$ and no superpotential, i.e. $W=0$. So we have $F$ couples of chiral superfields $(Q_i,\tilde{Q}_i)$ with flavour index $i=1,\dots,F$; $Q^i$ has gauge charge $+1$ and lives in the fundamental representation of $SU(F)$ while $\tilde{Q}_i$ has gauge charge $-1$ and lives in the antifundamental rep. of $SU(F)$. The (only one) $D$-equation reads
$$
D=Q^\dagger_i Q^i -\tilde{Q}^\dagger_i\tilde{Q}^i=0 \ ,
$$
where a $\langle \rangle$ is understood whenever $Q$ or $\tilde{Q}$ appear. Using the definition (1) of the moduli space we find that the number of putative complex scalar fields parametrizing the moduli space is $2F$. We have one $D$-term equation only, which provides one real condition, plus gauge invariance
$$
Q^i\to e^{i\alpha}Q^i \quad,\quad \tilde{Q}^i\to e^{-i\alpha}\tilde{Q}^i \ ,
$$
which provides another real condition. Therefore, the dimension of the moduli space is
$$
\dim_{\mathbb{C}}\mathcal{M}_{cl}=2F-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}=2F-1 \ .
$$

Using now definition (2), the only gauge invariants we can construct are the *mesons*
$$
M^i_j=Q^i\tilde{Q}_j \ .
$$
These are $F^2$ complex parameters. To find the classical relations, we first notice that $M=(M^i_j)$ is a rank 1, $F\times F$ matrix. This implies that the meson matrix has only one non-vanishing eigenvalue $\lambda_0$, which means
$$
\det (M-\lambda \mathbf{1})=\lambda^{F-1}(\lambda-\lambda_0)(-1)^{F} \ .
$$
Recalling that for a matrix $A$
$$
\epsilon_{i_1i_2\dots i_F}A^{i_1}_{j_1}A^{i_2}_{j_2}\cdots A^{i_F}_{j_F}=\det A \;\epsilon_{j_1j_2\dots j_F} \ ,
$$
with $\epsilon_{i_1 i_2\dots i_F}$ the fully antisymmetric tensor with $F$ indices, we have
$$
\epsilon_{i_1i_2\dots i_F}(M^{i_1}_{j_1}-\lambda \delta^{i_1}_{j_1})(M^{i_2}_{j_2}-\lambda \delta^{i_2}_{j_2})\cdots (M^{i_F}_{j_F}-\lambda \delta^{i_F}_{j_F})=\lambda^{F-1}(\lambda-\lambda_0)(-1)^{F} \epsilon_{j_1j_2\dots j_F} \ ,
$$
which means that from the left hand side, only the coefficients of the terms $\lambda^F$ and $\lambda^{F-1}$ survives. The next contribution, proportional to $\lambda^{F-2}$, should vanish, that is
$$
\epsilon_{i_1i_2\dots i_F} M^{i_1}_{j_1} M^{i_2}_{j_2} \epsilon^{j_1 j_2\dots j_F}=0 \ . \tag{3}
$$

#### The problem

Now comes the crucial point in which I disagree with the conclusion of Bertolini. He says that (3) gives us $(F-1)^2$ equations, i.e. the classical relations we talked before. If so, the space parametrized by the mesons has dimension
$$
\dim_{\mathbb{C}} \mathcal{M}_{cl}=F^2-(F-1)^2=2F-1 \ ,
$$
which agree with the previous result.

However, to me it seems that (3) gives us $\Big(\frac{F(F-1)}{2}\Big)^2$ independent equations, so the dimensions of the two spaces are not the same. In support of my conclusion, I also say that equation (3) seems to be the condition for which all the $2\times 2$ minors of the matrix $M$ vanishes. In fact, this is equivalent to say that $M$ is rank 1. However, for a $n\times m$ matrix, there are $\begin{pmatrix}n\\ k\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}m\\ k\end{pmatrix}$ minors of order $k$. So fo our $F\times F$ matrix $M$, there are
$$
\begin{pmatrix}F\\ 2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}F\\ 2\end{pmatrix}=\Big(\frac{F(F-1)}{2}\Big)^2 
$$
minors of order $2$. Saying that $M$ is rank 1 is equivalent to say that all these $2\times 2 $ minors should vanish, and this gives us $\Big(\frac{F(F-1)}{2}\Big)^2$ equations which is the same number of equations that comes from (3), from my point of view.

Now, I assume that there's something I miss; I'll be glad if someone could point me out where I am wrong.

[1]: M.A. Luty and W. Taylor, *Varieties of vacua in classical supersymmetric gauge theories*, Phys. Rev. D **53** (1996) 3399 [[hep-th/9506098](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9506098)]

Comment: How did you get the 2x2 minors condition?

Comment: First from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)#Determinantal_rank_%E2%80%93_size_of_largest_non-vanishing_minor) we have that the rank of a matrix is the largest order of any non zero minor. So, if the rank is 1, every minor should vanish, and so any 2x2 minor. The converse is also true, if you think at the Laplace expansion for the determinant, if every 2x2 minor vanish, then every 3x3 minor does it and so on, therefore the rank is 1. Moreover, if you look at the LHS of (3) you can convince yourself that you can write it as determinants of 2x2 submatrices of M.